# All of my events have disappeared in the new Photos app for OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, photos

I have just upgraded OSX Yosemite and have been looking at the new Photos app.  It seems all of my events have disappeared.  How do I get them back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option for working with events is to use the sidebar (cmd + alt + s or view → Show Sidebar). They will be listed there:

[image: screenshot]

Without using the sidebar they are listed in the Albums section:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thankyou.  Can I ask a related question... Should I be using Events or Albums?  Say I go to the Zoo with my family, take some pictures and then import into Photos.  Is that an Event or an Album?  I always used Events with iPhoto.

Comment: @rf_wilson Please ask this as a new question. No one can easily answer (or even see in many cases) a follow on question buried in the comments.

Comment: Woah! There's a sidebar in photos and it's actually useful! +10 thanks

Comment: @rf_wilson think that's more personal preference, but I'd say go with albums for Photos. They are more easily accessible in the sidebar for drag 'n drop for example.